# How to open again the minimized pop up window

Tags: .net

Here ther is one button. If we click that button pop up window will be opened.If i minimized that one and again i click that button means that minimized pop up window sholud be opened. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the popup window is part of your assembly, just keep track of a reference to it when you create it on the first click and on the second click just change the `WindowState` of the reference, like:

```
frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
```

If the popup window is an external app you can get a handle to it via `FindWindowEx` and then call `SetWindowPlacement`. They're both Windows API methods that can be called via PInvoke. More information can be found here:

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/setwindowplacement.html